# I canceled a OneDrive syncing and now have files with "-copy" added to the file name. How do I retain the file but remove "copy" from its name?

Tags: onedrive

I tried using OneDrive and found it was copying all the files from my home computer to my work computer so I stopped the process in the middle. I broke the connection, deleted OneDrive, and that removed my personal files that were downloaded, but now a huge number of my work files (pdfs, excel, word) have "-copy" added to the end of the file name. I know how it got there, but if anyone else at work were to see the file name, it would be confusing. How can I remove "-copy" from the file names?  I don't want to delete the files, just modify the file names to remove the copy designation.

Comment: If you're lazy and don't like to create a batch file, as suggested below, Microsoft's [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) have a Renamer tool included that can handle exactly what you want to do, plus more. Posting not as an answer, because I think a batch file, in case you only need the renaming once, is the more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify recursion or not.

This simple batch file will do what you ask but doesn't recurse directories.

```
@echo off

:: Remove or comment the following line when you have 
:: the results you want on your screen.
:: This script is harmless until you do.
Set DebugCommand=echo 

::If you want to recurse directories, a bit of additional work is required.

for %%f in (*.*) do call :RenameFiles "%%f"
goto :EOF

:: -----------------------------------------------------------------
:: Function - RenameFiles
:: Params   - %1 = the name of the input file
:: Purpose  - removes "-copy" from the file name
:: -----------------------------------------------------------------
:RenameFiles
Set InputFile=%~1
Set OutputFile="%InputFile:-copy=%"

:: If the files are still the same, then -copy wasn't in the name
if "%InputFile%"=="%OutputFile%" goto :EOF

%DebugCommand% rename "%InputFile%" "%OutputFile%"
goto :EOF
```